# PHP Issue: To execute another ur using PHP function file()

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a PHP CRON script that use to execute the external url using the code below every 5 minutes:
echo file("https://...");

This line of code is not working after i upgrade my server from VPS to Dedicated Server.
Is that anything to do to the WHM tweak, firewall, or security?

Comment: To further clarify my issue:
I have also tried "file_get_contents" but no luck.

And when i try to refresh my page in the browser url.
The url is executed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to enable the common PHP setting if the server setup by your self in VPS/Dedicated server.
You can also get the content from URL using the CURL method. It is proper method compare to file get contents because it provide more settings.
Notes: CURL setting must be enable on your server.

```
// Initiate curl session in a variable (resource)
$curl_handle = curl_init();

$url = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees";

// Set the curl URL option
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// This option will return data as a string instead of direct output
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute curl & store data in a variable
$curl_data = curl_exec($curl_handle);

curl_close($curl_handle);
```